# How to prevent env.render(mode='rgb_array') window popup?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I need to do the following on macos Big Sur 11.4, python 3.9.5, gym 0.18.3 to get frame as an array which is not returned by default for bipedal walker env.

```
import gym


env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v3')
state = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
```

This does the job however, I don't want a window popping up because this will be called by pytest so, that window beside requiring a virtual display if the tests are run remotely on some server, is unnecessary.